# Aggregate function as parameter in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm searching for a solution, but i can't find the answer. Is it possible to create procedure or function in mySQL that will take aggregate function as a parameter?
For example, if I call function 'myFunction(SUM)' it will use SUM as aggregate function, if I call myFuction(MAX) it will use MAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this using dynamic SQL -- that is, with `prepare` and `exec` statements.

If you want to do this inline, you might want something like:

```
select (case when myfunction = 'SUM' then sum(x)
             when myfunction = 'MAX' then max(x)
             . . .
        end) as custom_agg
```

I should also note that you cannot pass a function name in as a parameter.